# Dynamic object creation

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstableview, nswindow

I did created NSTableView, but this not displays on NSWindow. Code example:

```
NSTableView *tbl = [[NSTableView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,500,500)];
[window.contentView addSubview:tbl];
```

P.S.
I need make application without IBOutlets only

Comment: Note that tables generally expect to be inside a scroll view, so you almost certainly want to create one of them too.

Answer (score 1):

That code is correct. Make sure that you have created or loaded the window (i.e., `window` is not `nil`) and that you have given it a content view (`window.contentView` is not `nil`).

Also, don't forget to release `tbl`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NSTableView *tbl = [[NSTableView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,500,500)];
[window setContentView:tbl];
[tbl release];
```

Assuming your `window` object isn't `nil` and that you've initialized it correctly.

**Update:** see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/OpeningClosingWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000226-CJBCCCEF) for info about making an `NSWindow` visible; specifically:

> Opening a window—that is, making a window visible—is normally accomplished by placing the window into the application's window list by invoking one of the methods makeKeyAndOrderFront:, orderFront:

So, after the code above, added the following to make the window visible:

```
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

Answer (score -1):

why don't you use uitableview?
it is standard class for table view.

UITableView *tbl = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,500,500)] autorelease];
[window.contentView addSubview:tbl];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: The question was tagged OSX, so it's assumed to be for a Mac Cocoa app, not an iOS app, which is where you use UITableView.

Comment: NSTableView is the standard table view class in Cocoa. UITableView is the standard table view class in Cocoa Touch.